# Plasma generated with gas and how far does it penetrate the skin

Tags: magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, inert-gases

I know Far Infrared can penetrate the body’s tissues 1.5 inches (almost 4 cm) beneath the skin.
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3699878/

But how far will a plasma field generated with argon or neon gas penetrate the skin / body?

See video dealing with plasma and wound healing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TeNlgi7so1Q
Thanks

Comment: Why do you think a plasma will penetrate the skin, much less why it would be comparable to far infrared light?

Comment: How hot and fast is it? There are no reasons why one can't make a hypersonic gas stream that can cut you in half in seconds from neon or any other gas you would like to use.

Comment: @JonCuster I think CuriousOne answered your question :-D but Im looking into how plasmas are being used in wound healing this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TeNlgi7so1Q

Comment: I could imagine that plasmas would be good for disinfecting things (so long as they are "cool" plasmas and do not ablate the material) but ionized particles tend to damage and/or destroy living cells, not heal them.